# Splitting a file every two characters/digits and adding new line every 16 double characters/digits

Tags: ruby, file, split

I have a file that needs to be split with a `-` and then split into groups of two, every 16 characters/digits a new line needs to be added

Original look of file:

> ```
> aaa 3aaa aaa a4aaa
> b1bbbb2bbbbbb bb
> c 4cccc cc c5ccc cc
> ```

Expected output of file:

> ```
> aa - a3 - aa - aa - aa - a4 - aa - aa
> b1 - bb - bb- 2b- bb - bb - bb - bb
> cc - 4c - cc - cc - cc - cc - 5c - cc
> ```

I've done a lot of research and the discovered that using `.split(" - ")` will do the splitting with `-`, but how would I group the characters into "bundles"?

So far I've tried `.gsub(/\[a-zA-Z]/)` obviously that didn't work because I'm terrible with regex..

I've also tried using `.split("\n")` to see if I would be able to split the file into lines and then figure out a way to groups.

Comment: Pls provide/explain desired output for given input

Comment: @WandMaker There you go, hope that makes it better

Comment: It is still not clear how you got the values after aplit for given values before split

Comment: @WandMaker I didn't that the whole point of this question...

Comment: The output you gave is weird, why are some in groups of three, others groups of two, and others just one? How do you want it to decide where to split?

Comment: @rp.beltran Think of this like a hexeditor

Comment: @Bam There has to be some logical correlation between input and output.  The question is very confusing

Comment: I'm not seeing the hex editor thing. Here is a screenshot of a hex editor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor#/media/File:Hexedit-screenshot.png notice how it is consistently two characters per group, not one to three.

Comment: The actual amount of digits per grouping in a hex editor is based on the amount of bytes representing the binary value it is looking at. It would be log16(bits),  in the case of characters probably log16(256), which is equal to 2, not a variable amount, and so I'm not sure your analogy is very useful here.

Comment: @rp.beltran Alright I edited the question, that should make it a little bit easier, I'll figure out the rest

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but I have the start of a hexeditor that I was creating, it's on hold now for research, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113184/format-of-hexeditor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it if your file is already grouped into the correct number of characters like you show in your input. If this is not the case, let me know and I can fix it.

```
#Example input
input = "aaa 3aaa aaa a4aaa
b1bbbb2bbbbbb bb
c 4cccc cc c5ccc cc"

#Prints the output
puts input.split("\n").map{|line| line.gsub(/\s+/, "").scan(/.{1,2}/).join(' - ')}.join("\n")
```

This works by first splitting the file at new lines, then with each line it removes the space, as per your example you do not appear to be counting those, and then it puts them into groups of two, and merges those groups with dashes and spaces between. Finally, it joins all of the lines back into one string, but puts the new line character back in so it displays properly.

## Edit

Per your comment that your input is not already grouped to size, you can try this:

```
input = "aaa 3aaa aaa a4aaa b1bbbb2bbbbbb bb c 4cccc cc c5ccc cc"

puts input.gsub(/\s+/, "").scan(/.{1,16}/).map{ |line| line.scan(/.{1,2}/).join(' - ') }.join("\n")
```

which outputs:

```
aa - a3 - aa - aa - aa - a4 - aa - ab
1b - bb - b2 - bb - bb - bb - bb - c4
cc - cc - cc - c5 - cc - cc - c
```

It works the same way as the last one, but splits by group of up to 16 characters instead of by new line character.

Comment: It is not grouped correctly, that was an example file

Comment: Does that fix it for you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to try using the scan method to separate the string into groups of 2 chars. 
Then you can do some text changes in a for loop to add in the new line breaks.
I was thinking something like this:

```
fileString = "aa - a3 - aa - aa - aa - a4 - aa - a
b1b - b - bb- 2b- bbb - bb - b - b
c - 4c - c - ccc - c - c - 5 - ccc - cc"
fileArray = fileString.gsub(/\r/," ").gsub(/\n/," ").gsub("-", "").gsub(" ", "").scan(/../)
for i in (fileArray.length-1).downto(0)
    if i % 15 == 0 && i != 0
        fileArray[i] = "\n"+fileArray[i]
    end
end
fileString = fileArray.join(" ")
```

**EDIT:**

Another option with less gsub'bing could be as follows:

```
fileString = "aa - a3 - aa - aa - aa - a4 - aa - a
b1b - b - bb- 2b- bbb - bb - b - b
c - 4c - c - ccc - c - c - 5 - ccc - cc"
fileArray = fileString.strip().gsub(/([\- ])/,"").scan(/../)
for i in (fileArray.length-1).downto(0)
    if i % 15 == 0 && i != 0
        fileArray[i] = "\n"+fileArray[i]
    end
end
fileString = fileArray.join(" ")
```

Comment: That's a lot of `gsub`ing to accomplish one thing, is that the only way..?

Comment: could do `fileArray = fileString.strip().gsub(/([\- ])/,"").scan(/../)` instead...

Answer (score 1):

@rp.beltran's example:

```
input = "aaa 3aaa aaa a4aaa
b1bbbb2bbbbbb bb
c 4cccc cc c5ccc cc"
```

First remove spaces and newlines:

```
str = input.gsub(/[\s\n]/, '')
  #=> "aaa3aaaaaaa4aaab1bbbb2bbbbbbbbc4ccccccc5ccccc"
```

Now compute the number of lines and map each to the desired string:

```
(str.size/16.0).ceil.times.map { |i| str[i*16, 16].scan(/..?/).join(' - ') }
  #=> ["aa - a3 - aa - aa - aa - a4 - aa - ab",
  #    "1b - bb - b2 - bb - bb - bb - bb - c4",
  #    "cc - cc - cc - c5 - cc - cc - c"]
```

Note: `"cat"[1, 9999] #=> "at"`.

Comment: What does `.ceil` do..?

Comment: Bam, `ceil`'s receiver is a float, so look in the docs for [Float#ceil](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-ceil). `3.4.ceil #=> 4`, `3.0.ceil #=> 3`.